# Unable to add check in SQL server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

I m trying to add a check in sql server that its column value should not be greater than other tables count but it isn't working

```
alter table person add cnt int
    constraint CK_CONSS check (pnum < select count(*) from Gender)
```

Comment: Now which one is it, MySQL or SQLServer?

Comment: If the OP is using a check constraint and expects anything to happen, assume it is SQL Server.  MySQL doesn't implement `check` constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `User Defined Function` which counts the number of rows in `Gender` to check the values inserted into `person` table `pnum` Column.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Count_checkfn()
returns INT
AS
  BEGIN
      RETURN
        (SELECT Count(*) FROM   Gender)
  END

ALTER TABLE person
  ADD CONSTRAINT CK_CONSS CHECK (pnum<dbo.Count_checkfn())
```

### Demo

```
CREATE TABLE Count_table(Count_column INT)
CREATE TABLE Check_table(Check_Column INT)

INSERT Count_table
VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1)

Go
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Count_checkfn()
returns INT
AS
  BEGIN
      RETURN
        (SELECT Count(*)
         FROM   dbo.Count_table)
  END
Go

ALTER TABLE Check_table
  ADD CONSTRAINT Count_Check CHECK (Check_Column<dbo.Count_checkfn())

INSERT INTO Check_table VALUES (1) -- Works

INSERT INTO Check_table VALUES (6) -- Insert Failed because only 5 records present 
                                   -- in Count Table
```